# Scala - How to get an object from an RDD after filtering

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have filtered an RDD of `Sale` objects to get a single `Sale` by id. But how do I get a `Sale` object? I've tried mapping to Sale but it also returns an array. As well as `.take(1)`

As far as I understand map transformation just returns another RDD and it is expected behavior. Since RDD is an immutable data structure.

```
val sales: RDD[Sale] = oldSales.filter(sale => sale.ID == "123-0567").map(s => s)

val filteredSale: Sale = ??
```

Comment: Why do you need to extract an object from an RDD? You're forcing workers to send back data to driver host, in this way.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin this is for testing my logic locally

Comment: So, is it code that you will not use in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
val filteredSale = sales.collect.head.getAs[Sale](0)
```